# Do threads stop on their own in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, looper

Im a little confused on to how threading works. I worked with them a while ago when I made a FTP client for one of my apps, but only used to it start downloads and refresh the file list, nothing to snazzy. But now, im going to be using it extensively for getting information form a JSON server and populating data. I have gotten it to work, but I want to make sure I am doing it right. Here is the code.

```
public void getGameList()
{
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            List<Game> mGames = new ArrayList<Game>();
            mApiHelper = new ApiHelper("");
            mGames = mApiHelper.getGames("name=Metal&&platform=Microsoft%20Xbox%20360");
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.what = 1;
            msg.obj = mGames;
            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Now, I dont need that thread to keep running, but from my impressions of threads, they just stay there until they are told to go away. Is that true? Do I need to wrap the code in something like a while loop like Ive seen in other examples? Or will this thread stop once it sees there is nothing else to do?

Comment: You're right in the latter, once the `run()` method is finished the `Thread` dies.

Comment: So in this case, once the message is sent the thread dies? If that is the case then perfect. I just didnt want to have 20 threads running because this code will be used often

Comment: If _the code is run so often_ the **do not** spawn new threads each time. This is **very** expensive. Use a `ThreadPool` such as an [`ExecutorService`](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html).

Comment: By often I mean like once per activity. Just didnt want 10 open if there is 10 activities